# Parse column in CSV file

Tags: java, string

I have several columns of data in a csv file. I was able to isolate the column I want, but now I need to delete "|" and "&" symbols contained in the column. Can anyone help me out? The relevant code is as follows:

```
// CSVRead.java
//Reads a Comma Separated Value file and prints its contents.

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class CSVRead{

 public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

   BufferedReader b1 = 
        new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Reactions.csv"));

   BufferedWriter b2 = 
        new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Write1.txt"));

   BufferedWriter b3 = 
        new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Write2.txt"));

   Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[+]");
   Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("\t");
   Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("<=>");
   Pattern p4 = Pattern.compile(" ");
   Pattern p5 = Pattern.compile("RSP_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");

   ArrayList<String> reactions = new ArrayList<String>();//List to hold all reactions
   ArrayList<String> reactionID = new ArrayList<String>();//List to hold all reactions
   ArrayList<String> genes = new ArrayList<String>();//List to hold all genes

   String strRead; String strWrite;

   while ((strRead=b1.readLine())!=null) {
     String splitarray[] = strRead.split("\t");
     String firstentry = splitarray[0];
     String secondentry = splitarray[7];
     b3.write(secondentry);
     b3.newLine();
   } 

   b2.close(); 
   b3.close();

 } //main()

} // CSVRead
```

I think I might have to use the expression:

```
genes.add(splitarray[7].replace("|",""));
```

for example. But I'm not sure where to put it or if it's correct. Thanks for you help,

Kbball

Comment: There are libraries for this type of work, e.g. `OpenCSV`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct , but keep in mind the original string is not changed. Genes.add however will contain string with | replaced you can do same for & also.

Comment: Thanks. Now how to I write out the string with "|" replaced? I tried: b3.write(genes.add(splitarray[7].replace("|",""))) but that failed.

Comment: b3.write(splitarray[7].replace("|","")) will work. what you are printing will result in whether elemnt was added to arraylist or not a boolean .

Comment: That works. Unfortunately when I write b3.write(splitarray[7].replace("&","")) on the next line it seems to cancel my previous command, so I see the "|" come back. Is there any way I can include both instructions into the write command, so that neither one is cancelled?

Thanks.

Comment: Nvm I got it. You just have to use another .replace. Thanks for your help!